# Form Load and Unload

Tags: forms

What are the functions  in Form API that perform the task just like form load and unload
I want to perform few checks when the form loads and delete those checks when the form is unloaded.

```
           function form_example_form($form, &$form_state) {
                 $form['search'] = array(
                '#type' => 'textfield',
                '#title' => t('Search for Members'),
                '#size' => 60,
                '#maxlength' => 128
                );
                $form['submit'] = array(
                '#type' => 'submit',
                '#value' => t('Search'),
                '#submit' => array('myform_newform_submit'),
                );
                 $header = array(
                    array('data' => t('ID'), 'field' => 't.id'),
                    array('data' => t('First Name'), 'field' => 't.fname'),
                    array('data' => t('Last Name'), 'field' => 't.lname'),
                    'operations' => array('data' => t('Operations'), 'colspan' => 2),
                  );
                if((variable_get('results'))!="") {

               $query = db_select('myform', 't')
              ->extend('TableSort')        //Sorting Extender
              ->orderByHeader($header)
              ->extend('PagerDefault')
              ->condition('lname',variable_get('results'),'=')
              ->limit(2)
              ->fields('t', array('id', 'fname', 'lname'));
              $results = $query->execute();
              foreach($results as $node)
              {
               $rows[]=array(
                    'id' => $node->id,
                    'first_name' =>$node->fname,
                    'last_name' => $node->lname,
                   'modify' => l('Modify', 'myform/modify/'.$node->id),
                    'delete' => l('Delete', 'myform/delete/' . $node->id));
               }
               }
               else
               {
               $rows = array(); 
               }
            $form['pager_table'] = array(
              '#theme' => 'table',
              '#header' => $header,
              '#rows' => $rows,
              '#empty' => t('Empty Rows')
              );
              // attach the pager theme
              $form['pager_pager'] = array('#theme' => 'pager');
                return $form;
                                     }

                             function form_example_form_submit($form,&$form_state)
               {
        variable_set('results',$form_state['values']['search']);
                   }
```

Now when I change the link how do I free the variable at form unload

Comment: what is the idea behind form load and unload ? make a ctrl+f and search here http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7

Comment: I want to run a javascript function at the time of page load before the form items are displayed and when I move to some other link  from this page I again want to run a function.Example:-Suppose I want to enter a session id at the time of loading the page and I want to free the session id at the time of page unload.

Comment: Can't you just add javascript with drupal_add_js() http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7 

If you need to add it to another modules form you can use hook_form_alter or if its your own form then add it at the start of the form function

Comment: what in the case where I want to assign a value to session at the time of loading and deleting the session at the time of unloading the form

Comment: In all probability you are thinking the problem wrong from drupal sense. can you elaborate on what's your usecase? Why do u wish to set a session on form load and unset on form_submit ( I hope thats what you mean to say when u say form_unload) do you wish to pass data during form submission process? Elaborate and you will get a better answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets try this method

on your form

```
function form_example_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $name = 'myname';
  $value = 'nikhil';
  variable_set($name, $value);
  // Your form elements goes here ...   
}

function form_example_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $name = 'myname';
  $myname = variable_get($name, $default = NULL);
  echo $myname; // will print nikhil
  variable_del($name);

}
```

As i dont know any Form Unload event i will do

```
drupal_add_js("jQuery(document).unload(function() { 
//make an AJAX call to clear the value });", 'inline');
```

in javascript

Good luck.

Comment: what if the variable is set in submit function and retrieved in form function then how can we delete the variable when we visit other link i.e form unloads

Comment: If you want a more specific answer elaborate your question.